# Failed to convert UTF-16 string buffer created in C++ into python using SWIG

Tags: python, unicode, swig

I have a C++ function I want to use in Python:

```
struct DataWrap
{
    wchar_t* data;
    int size;
}

extern int fun1( const char* szInBuffer, unsigned int inSize,DataWrap* buff);
```

`fun1` takes an array of `char`s given in `szInBuffer` with size of `inSize` and returns a newly allocated  UTF-16 string in `dataWrap->data`

I would like to use this function `fun1` from Python.

```
%typemap(argout) DataWrap* buff{
                int byteorder = -1;
                $input = PyUnicode_DecodeUTF16( (const char*)($1->data), ($1->size)*sizeof(wchar_t) , NULL, &byteorder);
}
```

this does work, but there is a memory leak here 
as the `dataWrap->data` allocated by `fun1` is never released.

I tried to fix that like this:

```
%typemap(argout) DataWrap* buff{
            int byteorder = -1;
            $input = PyUnicode_DecodeUTF16( (const char*)($1->data), ($1->size)*sizeof(wchar_t) , NULL, &byteorder);
            delete $1;
        }
```

and now the code crashes.

What am I doing wrong? Is that the correct why to work with SWIG in order to get a UTF-16 string into Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `freearg` typemap:

```
%typemap(freearg) DataWrap *buff {
    delete $1->data;
}
```

Also, you had `delete $1;`.  Should it be `delete $1->data`?

**Edit**

I discovered another issue when playing with this problem that may be related to your issue.  If you are on Windows and your implementation of `fun1` is in a different DLL than the SWIG wrapper code, make sure to make both DLLs link to the same C Runtime DLL (via the `/MD` compiler switch in Microsoft VC++, for example), since the memory would then be allocated (with `new` I assume) in one DLL and freed in another.

Here's the code I was playing with.  It may help you.  It also includes a typemap to eliminate sending the string and size from Python and a typemap to generate a temporary DataWrap object so it doesn't have to be passed as well.  In the implementation file `x.cpp` I faked an implementation of converting the string to UTF16 that only works with simple ASCII strings for something to work with.

Also note I got it to work without using the `freearg` typemap, although using the typemap worked for me as well.

#### makefile

```
_x.pyd: x_wrap.cxx x.dll
    cl /MD /nologo /LD /Zi /EHsc /W4 x_wrap.cxx /Id:\dev\python27\include -link /LIBPATH:d:\dev\python27\libs /OUT:_x.pyd x.lib

x.dll: x.cpp x.h
    cl /MD /nologo /Zi /LD /EHsc /W4 x.cpp

x_wrap.cxx: x.h x.i
    swig -python -c++ x.i
```

#### x.i

```
%module x

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4211 4706)
%}

%{
    #include "x.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>

%typemap(in) (const char *szInBuffer,unsigned int inSize) {
   if (!PyString_Check($input)) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expecting a string");
       return NULL;
   }
   $1 = PyString_AsString($input);
   $2 = PyString_Size($input);
}

%typemap(in, numinputs=0) DataWrap* buff (DataWrap temp) {
   $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap(argout) DataWrap* buff {
    int byteorder = -1;
    $result = PyUnicode_DecodeUTF16((const char*)($1->data), ($1->size)*sizeof(wchar_t), NULL, &byteorder);
    delete [] $1->data;
}

%include "x.h"
```

#### x.h

```
#ifdef API_EXPORTS
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct DataWrap
{
    wchar_t* data;
    int size;
};

extern "C" API void fun1(const char* szInBuffer, unsigned int inSize, DataWrap* buff);
```

#### x.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define API_EXPORTS
#include "x.h"

API void fun1(const char* szInBuffer, unsigned int inSize, DataWrap* buff)
{
    unsigned int i;
    buff->size = inSize;
    buff->data = new wchar_t[inSize];
    for(i = 0; i < inSize; i++)
        buff->data[i] = szInBuffer[i];
}
```

#### Output

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import x
>>> x.fun1('abc')
u'abc'
```

Comment: Thanks mate , I'll check it. do i need the conversion $1 = PyString_AsString($input); doesn't swig do it ?  i need to return two values the return value of fun1 and the string in buff so returning buff to the $result is not an option

Comment: The manual conversion lets you send just the string instead of the string and it's length, but you don't have to do it.  If you want to return two values you have to create a tule of the result instead.  I'll update later if you need to see how to do it.